# Who's this Pokemon?

Tags: knowledge, riddle

The requested Pokemon belongs to the original ones, often called the real ones, i.e. the first 151 Pokemon.

1. I do what I know best, but people don't appreciate it!
2. This makes me feel bad, I punish them!

<sub>More clues upon request, I guess :)</sub>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are

> Jigglypuff,  based on the cartoon where she draws on people's faces when they fall asleep after hearing her sing

Comment: Correct! Do you think this was bad riddle? It got a downvote.. :/ I was thinking of making more, but if there are not good, then I shouldn't!

Comment: I'd say go for it, this one was a little on the easy side though.  Maybe see if you can make them a little tougher somehow.

Comment: The first battle is always easy @AndrewF! :) Thanks!

Comment: This was more of a trivia than a riddle.

Comment: @Zikato Exactly. Those who've watched anime will remember :)

Comment: @Zikato I added the tag [tag:trivia]. Hope my next question [First Gym: Brock! Who's this Pokemon?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41027/first-gym-brock-whos-this-pokemon) to be better!