# First Gym: Brock! Who's this Pokémon?

Tags: knowledge, movies, riddle

This question is the second one in [a series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40872/a-pokemon-riddle-who-am-i) of Poké-related questions I hope that I can ask.

Who's this Pokémon that:

1. Was (already?) released by the time the generation that has *almost* as many Pokémon as the
   number a byte can hold, was released.
2. Has the same name as what was the major event on a Disney Princess's
   Birthday, in a cartoon movie.
3. The movie was released at the same year as the one I got into Uni,
   listed in Greece list in my [Travel](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/travel/), in the place that Arsenal
   is notorious for. Indexing for that may, or may not be, the reverse
   of what one would expect. You can check the year I was born to determine if indixing starts from the start of the list or from the end.
4. Brock has a hard time deciding if he has the advantage or the
   disadvantage over it!

Comment: Strongly recommend not including clues that link to external websites about yourself. :/

Comment: @IanMacDonald I wouldn't! But in my 1st question I was downvoted for my question being to easy, so I wanted to make it a bit harder..Will have it in mind though for the next gym!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's

> [Lanturn](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lanturn_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

Clue 1

> Generation 2 had 251 total Pokémon (100 new Pokémon combined with Generation 1's 151), *almost* 255

Clue 2

> Rapunzel's parents (and the rest of the kingdom) release lanterns on her birthday each year in *Tangled*

Clue 3

> Arsenal is mocked for usually terminating in 4th position. In your list, the 4th element **from the end** is an island that was visited in 2010 – the same year *Tangled* was released (though interestingly not in Greece, where it wasn't released until January of 2011). It could not be indexed from the start, because that destination was visited in 1995, and you were too young to be in university.

Clue 4

> Lanturn is weak to Ground type moves (which many Rock type Pokémon have access to), but Brock's Rock types are weak to Lanturn's Water moves

Comment: Will, I updated my question with the 3rd clue. Please, take a moment and retry! The list of the places I have in Greece are marked by the time of year. We are interesting in finding the list item in the place that Arsenal (the football team in Premier League) is usually mocked for terminating at every season. That year is the same as the release year of the movie in Clue 2. Let me know if this helps!  (I only said it was at the same year as the one I got into the university to help the reader determine if indexing starts from the start or the end of the list..

Comment: I thought it was ***SPOILER*** Sudowoodo, but don't want to look at the other website 0:P

Comment: @ABcDexter It's okay... looking makes the clue _more confusing_ than it already is. :| I've been staring at it for an hour and I still don't understand what I'm supposed to be indexing or how or what relevance any of it has other than potentially cluing the year 2010 (or possibly 2011 in Greece).

Comment: Ok, a trivia: Frozen's princess Elsa had a 'coronation' on her birthday. It was released in 2013 :)

Comment: @ABcDexter why would you think it was that Pokemon? I mean I cannot see how you connected this to clue #4. Will, I will update your answer with my reasoning and if you don't like it, just discard it.

Comment: @ABcDexter I'm not sure what that trivia's got to do with your guess above, but I am curious about both. More trivia: Elsa is one of two Disney _queens_ (since she was coronated as you said; the clue says princess!) played by Idina Menzel.

Comment: @gsamaras Thanks for the edit! I was reading/interpreting the clue wrong the whole time! *facepalm*