# Who's this Pokemon? The last one

Tags: knowledge, movies, riddle

Based on [Who's this Pokemon?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40872/whos-this-pokemon) who's this Pokemon, that:

1. Is one of the first `b^e` Pokemon, where `b` is something related to
   a concept that distinguishes people, and `e` is something related to
   what every Pokemon Trainer tries to get. If you have watched the
   Pokemon cartoons, you will know that `e` didn't make sense for
   Gary's show-off.
2. Is the same type as of the best Pokemon of a Gym Leader (also in the
   first `b^e` Pokemon as above), that tend to make lives of Trainers,
   like me and you, hard.
3. Is somehow related to Euler!
4. Reminds us of the protagonist in a cartoon movie, where the voice of
   the sausage dog playing in that movie, reminds us of the voice of
   the creatures that are always grouped/narrated/talked-about together
   (`x` in number), in Shrek's movie. `x` is equal to the number of
   evolutions some Pokemon have.

---

I can give tips for 3, upon request. First answer to solve all 3 clues will be accepted.

Comment: This one was better :) keep going...

Comment: Thanks @ABcDexter! However, I think it received some downvotes as well. The linked question of mine also received some downvotes, so I think I will stop here. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is honestly a flimsy guess, but I'm going with

> [Ursaring](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ursaring_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), Dex #217

Clue 1

> `b`: ["There are *two* types of people"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/there-are-two-types-of-people)...
>  and
>  `e`: Our goal in each region is to win `8` badges
>  So our Pokémon is in the first $2^8 = 256$.
>
>  Interestingly, Gary Oak collected [10 gym badges in Kanto](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:Gary_badges.png).

Clue 2

> Anyone who's talked with people about the games will probably have heard many of them complain about [Whitney's Miltank](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Whitney%27s_Miltank). We're dealing with a Normal type.

Clue 3

> [Euler popularized $\pi$](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/mathematical-notation-past-future/); Ursaring is known by its circle.

Clue 4

> Mr. Weenie in Open Season (in which the main protagonist is Boog, a bear) and the `3` pigs in Shrek were voiced by [the same actor](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0970606). Many [evolutionary chains have three Pokémon](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_three-stage_evolution).

Comment: Damn you Will! :)

Comment: Wait... how does e == 8

Comment: @AvikMohan there are typically 8 gyms in a region, therefore 8 badges and e = 8

Comment: Oh e is just a variable. I thought in my brief look at the problem that it was supposed to be like e = 5(th letter of the alphabet) or 2.714.. (Euler's number) haha

Comment: Also Whitneys Miltank was a piece of ****. It took me forever to beat it

Comment: @Areeb personally I prefer challenging gyms..For example I know play Leaf Green and the Psychic gym was hard (nice!), while the Poison one was a piece of cake...! ;p

Comment: @gsamaras I do too, it's just that my Feraligator kept flinching so it was more annoying than challenging