# The thought of my prefix brings many a smile; My infix is, mathematically

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, poetry

Here's my first attempt at a Riley! Good luck!

> The thought of my prefix brings many a smile;
>
> Sit down, relax, or sleep for a while.
>
> My infix is, mathematically;
>
> One point six times five point eight, then less three.
>
> My suffix is a speech, mad and long;
>
> Which definitely is not a song.

Comment: Nice try! Very interesting!

Comment: -1 because I thought it would be about Pokemon. Was hoping to see something like my[Who's this Pokemon?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40872/whos-this-pokemon). Kidding! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Restaurant

Prefix

> Rest is a synonym for relax, etc. and people look forward to it wistfully, with smiles on their faces.

Infix

> [Tau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(geometry)#Tau_proposals) (twice pi) is approximately $6.28$, which is $1.6 * 5.8 - 3$. Clued in by @[Omega Krypton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131/omega-krypton).

Suffix

> Rant, which is an unhappy speech

Comment: FGITW, by two seconds!

Comment: +1 Obviously, I did not see your answer when I posted.

Comment: @hexomino If you had that would have been incredible speed on the typing.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer is

> Restaurant

The thought of my prefix brings many a smile; 
Sit down, relax, or sleep for a while.

> **Rest** - which means to relax and is pleasing for many people.

My infix is, mathematically;
One point six times five point eight, then less three.

> **Tau**, as pointed out by WAF's comment on Omega Krypton's answer $$ (1.6 \times 5.8) - 3 = 6.28 \approx 2\pi \equiv \tau  $$

My suffix is a speech, mad and long; 
Which definitely is not a song.

> **Rant** - A lengthy, angry impassioned speech.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

> Infix 1.6*5.8-3=6.28, which is 2*pi, so infix="pipi"

Comment: Could also produce rot13([cv gvzrf gjb vf gnh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(geometry)#Tau_proposals))