# My prefix is an H bent outwards minus end three

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

[Part 1 is here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74572/excited-raichus-riley-riddle) (not important to solving this one)

> My prefix is an H bent outwards minus end three;
>
> My infix weighs fourteen pounds, minus the letters in me;
>
> My suffix is an uncle's brother's grandsons, minus the first one;
>
> All together, I'm in machines, but don't get me stuck to you when you're done.

P.S. (not really a hint but still)

> You can assume the uncle in question has only one brother.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My prefix is an H bent outwards minus end three;

> pisces (- last 3 letters) = PIS
>  Thanks to Tom for finding this!

My infix weighs fourteen pounds, minus the letters in me;

> stone (-m -e) = STON

My suffix is an uncle's brother's grandsons, minus the first one;

> sons (- first letter) = ONS

All together, I'm in machines, but don't get me stuck to you when you're done.

> PISTONS

Comment: Word is right, reasoning for the infix and suffix is right, reasoning for the prefix is not. Keep looking!

Comment: Prefix looks like rot13 cvfprf

Comment: @Tom looks good!